# С чем связана ошибка (лог из PlayMarket ниже)

Tags: java, android

Ошибка возникла на устройстве Lenovo VIBE K10 (K10a40), Android 6.0

На других устройствах такой ошибки не возникало.

```
backtrace:

#00  pc 0000000000198c2c  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6mirror6Object15VisitReferencesILb0ELNS_17VerifyObjectFlagsE0ENS_2gc9collector17MarkObjectVisitorENS5_29DelayReferenceReferentVisitorEEEvRKT1_RKT2_+27)
#01  pc 0000000000198ebd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector9MarkSweep16ProcessMarkStackEb+100)
#02  pc 0000000000199ffb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector9MarkSweep12MarkingPhaseEv+162)
#03  pc 000000000019a283  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector9MarkSweep9RunPhasesEv+538)
#04  pc 000000000018fecd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector16GarbageCollector3RunENS0_7GcCauseEb+276)
#05  pc 00000000001b2509  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap22CollectGarbageInternalENS0_9collector6GcTypeENS0_7GcCauseEb+1468)
#06  pc 00000000001b3a63  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap16ConcurrentGCTask3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+82)
#07  pc 00000000001cd789  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor11RunAllTasksEPNS_6ThreadE+40)
#08  pc 0000000002413387  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat
```

Comment: Подобные ошибки никак не связаны с приложением. Проблема в системных библиотеках. Обращайтесь к производителю устройства!

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Значит я могу сообщить пользователю, что я ничего не могу в этом случае сделать и на этом устройстве приложение работать скорее всего не будет.

Comment: нужно детально разобраться в результате какого действия возникает эта ошибка. Возникает эта ошибка при запуске, или при нажатии какого то элемента. Таким образом можно сузить круг и попытаться оптимизировать тот код, что есть сейчас. Возможно поможет сброс настроек устройства до заводских или перепрошивка официальным образом. В любом случае, информации в вопросе слишком мало, чтобы дать вам ответ.

Comment: К сожалению, разобраться более детально затруднительно, т.к. подключить устройство к компьютеру, на котором разрабатывается приложение нет возможности. Единственное, что известно, что приложение "падает" на старте. Backtrace взят из PlayMarket консоли разработчика.